# Can I use en/em dash in markdown?

Tags: html, git, markdown, manual

I am writing a technical manual using git.

Is there any problem caused if I use en or em dash such as `&#8212;`?

(For example) Voltage: 5–12 V

Some people say, when this special character is rendered from Markdown to HTML, the rendered character might be broken in some websites.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Git, but I am curious as to who these "some people" are, since even Lynx knows how to render an em or en dash as plain text...

Comment: Nope, as long as it's UTF-8 from beginning to end (which should be the default everywhere nowadays), should be no problem..

Answer (score 6):

I'm a technical editor at Microsoft and, for over a decade now, I use the HTML code because it's easy to remember! More important is to know **when** to use an em dash or an en dash.

```
&mdash;

&ndash;
```

Use em dash like you would a colon, or use in pairs like you would parentheses.

I rarely use the en dash, because a hyphen will do.

Comment: That is a good alternative indeed. Upvoted.

Comment: [En dashes - Microsoft Style Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/style-guide/punctuation/dashes-hyphens/enes)

Answer (score 1):

[As seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52371734/6309), this should work.

But, [from experience](https://stackoverflow.com/a/170148/6309), that makes copy-pasting the content of your technical documentation sometimes frustrating is that em dash is used for command option (`--anoption`)